# What's the best tool to design casings/boxes?

Tags: cable-assemblies, cases

I often tend to build a prototype for a project and if I have something that's good enough I find a case that matches the prototype I've built. However, now I'm trying to do more of the design up front and would like to design the casing up front. The latest projects seem to involve more parts as well.

Which tools do you use? I would like something that could give me a 3D view of the assembly. As a hobbyist I'd like something that is free or cheap.

I'm looking at [Google's SketchUp](http://sketchup.google.com/) now which seem useful but kinda cumbersome for my task.

Comment: Best tool and free/cheap tend to be mutually exclusive. If you want a *good* 3D modeling tool, I'd point you to solidworks. However, that is very, **very** expensive (basically your company has to buy it for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SketchUp can be a little cumbersome in the beginning. I would urge you to stick with it. There are a lot of really great tutorials out there (start at http://sketchup.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=36207). I'd spend just an hour or two really getting familiar with the tools and see how you feel. I'm in the same situation--hobbyist, so free/cheap is the best option. I hated that I could never get things to 'snap' or align properly. A few videos later, I'm fairly competent, and don't feel lost anymore. If nothing else, learn about inference and alignment. That should take some of the frustration out of it and make you more productive.

Sorry I don't have any alternatives, but I hope SketchUp works out for you. Good luck!

Comment: I found this tool+blog that combines Eagle with SketchUp: http://eagleup.wordpress.com/, I'm going to try that too.

Comment: Ooh, excellent find!  I'll check that out as well. Thanks!